# Do unreferenced ThreadLocals get initialized?

Tags: java, thread-local

Assuming a system contains 2 threads. One of them interacts with a ThreadLocal while the other does not.

What happens to ThreadLocal in the class that does not interact with the ThreadLocal?

1. Is it ever initialized?
2. Does it take up any memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be only one ThreadLocal object. Each Thread has a lazily initialised map of values of all initialised ThreadLocal objects. It means only the first Thread will have an extra Map object with one value, and nothing will change for the second thread.

See ThreadLocal.setInitialValue() for details:

```
private T setInitialValue() {
    T value = initialValue();
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null)
        map.set(this, value);
    else
        createMap(t, value);
    return value;
}
```

and ThreadLocal.set():

```
public void set(T value) {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null)
        map.set(this, value);
    else
        createMap(t, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#initialValue%28%29):

> `protected T initialValue()`
>
> This method will be invoked the first time a thread accesses the variable with the get() method, unless the thread previously invoked the set(T) method, in which case the initialValue method will not be invoked for the thread. Normally, this method is invoked at most once per thread, but it may be invoked again in case of subsequent invocations of remove() followed by get().

This suggests that the ThreadLocal only gets initialized for the threads that interact with it.

As to your second question (whether it uses up any resources), the answer it likely to depend on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc :

```
each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, 
independently initialized copy of the variable.
```

each `Thread` instance (from `Thread.currentThread()`) holds a map of `ThreadLocal` objects it interact with. It have a field `threadLocals`, each of these instances are initialized in the `Thread` instance.